# How do I force YAML to retain quotes inside a block that uses variable substitution?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm writing an Ansible playbook and am running into a weird issue where my variables end up getting changed in unexpected ways. I have a variable, which is actually a multi-line string of JSON, which I declare using the block scalar (`>`) syntax. And if I just do that much, it works fine. However, I also need to substitute another variable inside of that string. And as soon as I do that, it ends up effectively stripping all of the double quotes from the string for some reason.

Here's a sample of what my YAML looks like:

```
vars:
  - policy: >
      {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "AddPerm",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "s3:GetObject",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{{ domain_name }}/*"
            }
        ]
      }
```

And while this does properly substitute the value of my `domain_name` variable into the string, like I said - it also strips all the quotes which results in exceptions during task execution. As a simple test, I added a task that saves the value of `"{{ policy }}"` to a text file just to see what was happening. And what I end up seeing is this:

```
{Version: 2012-10-17, Statement: [{Action: s3:GetObject, Principal: *, Resource: arn:aws:s3:::my.domain.com/*, Effect: Allow, Sid: AddPerm}]}
```

I'm actually trying to use this as a parameter in a different test, which expects a valid JSON string. And in that case, because the quotes get stripped away, the task throws an exception. How can I ensure the quotes are preserved in my multi-line string variable while still allowing me to use variable substitution inside it?

Comment: I wrote an answer, but the real problem is that you seem to have no idea what you actually want to do and you don't bother to show the code, so I expect an "*oh no, this is not what my next task expects*"-style of response.

Comment: And trying to define a list (`-`) without a name will undoubtedly cause a syntax error in Ansible. How is it that your narrative claims this is how your "*YAML looks like*" and you get such and such results with it? What software do you use to process that YAML if not Ansible?

Comment: Thanks! Your answer sent me down the correct path. Obviously I truncated things here to try and hone in on the crux of my question. In context it actually was valid syntax. Could also do without the condescending tone, next time!

Comment: I faced a vey similar issue. YAML docs says, '>' and '|' start a block `scalar`. I see scalar as a string or number or whatever, but certainly not as an object. So I'd say Ansible is doing something funny here. I also tried using a YAML parser and the value came back as a string. Inside Ansible it becomes an object. The only reasonable workaround is to accept that Ansible will convert this to an object and to use an appropriate filter to render the content. In your case (and mine) `to_json` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using list marker `-` for `vars` is a blatant syntax error and Ansible should throw one with the code piece you posted, if you really used it.

Having that removed...

> How can I ensure the quotes are preserved in my multi-line string variable while still allowing me to use variable substitution inside it?

This is **not** a multi-line string variable, but a definition of a data object (of dictionary type) in JSON.

An object doesn't have any "quotes inside" regardless if there was a variable substitution, or not. It is a data structure.

What you "*end up seeing*", in other words how a data structure is rendered on your screen, depends solely on the method used to display it.

---

If "*a different test, [ ] expects a valid JSON string*" then you must define a string. And to do that in YAML you can quote it:

```
vars:
  policy: >
    '{
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
          {
              "Sid": "AddPerm",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": "*",
              "Action": "s3:GetObject",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{{ domain_name }}/*"
          }
      ]
    }'
```

---

But you might as well retain the JSON data type and use a [filter for formatting data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data). Who knows what your next task is...

Comment: Sorry for getting in late, but I faced a very similar issue. I kinda disagree here. YAML block scalars don't need quotes. In fact adding quotes in a block scalar makes them part of the content. With a one line scalar, YAML requires to add quotes if your scalar starts with '{', otherwise YAML would try to parse a JSON object. On the other hand with block scalars (using '>' or '|' ) the quotes are 'implicit' and the content should never be treated as JSON object. There are probably reasons why Ansible behaves this way, which are probably around Jinja templating being possible everywhere.